# How to select data with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to retrieve all row of data within some date range with only 1 condition which is only retrieve first row of type 'balance' , i think my question should explain better with data sample.

**Here is my table *statement***

```
| date | type     | credit | debit | balance |
|   a  | balance  |        |       |  100.00 |
|   a  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   a  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   a  | debit    |        | 50.00 |         |
|   b  | balance  |        |       |  50.00  |
|   b  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   b  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   b  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   b  | balance  |        |       | -100.00 |
|   c  | debit    |        | 250.00|         |
```

**This is what i trying to do (expected result)**

I need to perform a query which return all row from date a to c but only first row with type balance

```
| date | type     | credit | debit | balance |
|   a  | balance  |        |       |  100.00 |
|   a  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   a  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   a  | debit    |        | 50.00 |         |
|   b  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   b  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   b  | credit   | 50.00  |       |         |
|   c  | debit    |        | 250.00|         |
```

What i know here is i can achieve by doing 2 different query

```
SELECT * FROM statement WHERE date >= a and date <= c and type = 'balance' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM statement WHERE date >= a and date <= c and type != 'balance' ORDER BY date ASC
```

Here is my question , For some reason i need to done this with 1 single query , How do i achieve this result by one query.

Comment: your first query is having limit 1 so you are getting only one row

Comment: other than Union? I tried it , but it screwed my php class ... I'm trying to dig for simpler query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try a UNION?

```
SELECT * FROM statement WHERE date >= a and date <= c and type = 'balance' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM statement WHERE date >= a and date <= c and type != 'balance' ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Union` with `distinct`

```
SELECT * FROM statement WHERE date >= a and date <= c and type = 'balance' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM statement WHERE date >= a and date <= c and type != 'balance' ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to give **both** `type = 'balance'` and `type != 'balance'` condition.it doesnot make any sense.the following query will fetch the same records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM statement 
WHERE date >= a and date <= c  ORDER BY type,date ASC
```

Comment: I think the CASE may help , read my question again , i want to first  row with type balance

Comment: @LeonArmstrong then why dont you use order by with type and than with date?

Comment: check the expected result , i want all row but the ignore the rows with type balance after the first was select